# ¿Por qué mi api creada en net core 5 y publicada en IIS local no se conecta a mi base de datos local?

Tags: api, .net-core, .net-5

Tengo una api creada en net core 5 la cual se conecta a un base de datos de sql server y lista los registro de una tabla. Desde el visual studio anda sin problema, se conecta a la base y devuelve los datos, pero una vez que lo publico y creo el sitio en el iis me muestra un error 500 en el navegador. Yo supongo que debe ser algo de la base de datos porque tengo otros sitios publicados que no se conectan a una bd y funciona sin problemas, incluso probé con una api que no tiene una conexion a una base de datos y funciona perfectamente. Probé habilitar y usar el usuario 'sa' para conectarme, pero sucede lo mismo, desde el visual funciona pero desde iis no, además probé configurar la cadena de conexion en el iis desde la opcion de "cadenas de conexión" y tampoco funciona. Dejo el código de la cadena de conexión en el visual:

*appsetting.json*:

```
  "ConnectionStrings": {
"main": "Server=SEBA-PC\\SQLEXPRESS;Database=Northwind;User ID=sa;Password=123456"}
```

IIS
[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Comment: Posiblemente debas habilitar las conexiones TCP/IP en la BD para permitir el acceso remoto.

Comment: Muchas gracias, es correcto lo que me decis, probé eso que me comentas y me funciono